# permissions - PHP and FTP

Tags: php, linux, permissions

How to setup users/groups so both PHP/Apache and proFTPD has full access to files/dirs?

FTP user

```
Username: webadmin
User ID: 1001
Home dir: /var/www
Shell: /usr/sbin/nologin
Primary group: www-data

Move home dir if changed: yes
Change user ID on files: home dir
Change group ID on files: home dir
Modify user in other modules: yes
```

When logging in on the FTP with `webadmin` all files are listed but with no write rights!?

Comment: You will probably get more responses on serverfault.com, which is aimed at system administration questions. I have flagged it to the moderators, hopefully they will move it for you.

Comment: Without knowing what your security model is, its not posible to give an answer - however that you expecting files to be writeable by the group the webserver runs as implies the model is seriously flawed.

Comment: @symcbean, how would you then setup the users/groups? :)

Comment: Readable by webserver uid (probably via 'other') but not owned by webserver uid/group. For any files / dirs explicitly intended to be writeable by webser uid, then, again, these permissions allowed via 'other'. A specific group for users who can modify the files/dirs - group ownership set accordingly and group sticky bit set on dirs (assuming the installation does not use fastCGI running as a different user from the webserver or suPHP)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give multiple users access to something then you should use groups.

First make sure that all of your necessary web 'users' are members of a certain group, probably www-data.

```
usermod -a -G www-data webadmin
```

*Add the user 'webadmin' to the 'www-data' group.*

Next, change the group of the files to this group:

```
chgrp -R www-data files/dirs
```

*Recursively set the group of files/dirs to www-data.*

Finally, change the permissions of the directory in question to allow full access to all members of its group:

```
chmod -R g+rwx files/dirs
```

*Recursively give group members read, write and execute permissions to files/dirs*

Comment: when doing `chgrp -R www-data *` nothing is happening.. When logged in on the FTP the owner is still `proftpd`

Comment: `chgrp -R www-data *` will recursively set the group for everything in the current directory (Not including the current directory, or hidden files in the current directory) to www-data. If you run `ls -l` this should be reflected in the group permissions.  Are you sure you're running the chgrp command from the correct directory?